# Use Wrapper Class for C#

Tags: c#, .net, dll

This is probably an obvious question, but where do I put the dll for a .NET wrapper class, SoundTouchNet, to use in a C# project? I copied the .dll into Windows/Microsoft.NET/assembly/GAC_MSIL, but when I type in "using SoundTouchNet," the compiler can't find it. Here's the site: http://code.google.com/p/soundtouchnet/

I downloaded the dll's for the C++ SoundTouch library and put the .lib in VC/lib, .h in VC/include, and the .dll in System32. Is that also right?

Thanks!

Edit: Does anyone know also how to connect the SoundTouchNet library with the C++ SoundTouch? As mentioned, I have now successfully added the SoundTouchNet reference to the project. Now what? Do I need to do anything with the SoundTouch library, or is this independent from it? Thanks so much for all of your responses!

Comment: Did you add that DLL as a reference in your project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i think you have missed to add reference of that DLL into project. Add reference to your project

```
Project>  Reference > Add Reference > Browse > Select the DLL
```

for more information [see this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a reference to the dll file.

`using Sound...` simply removes the need to write `SoundTouchNet.RandomFunction()` every time.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to understand the difference between assembly references and `using` directives. A `using` directive such as

```
using SoundTouchNet;
```

*just* imports the namespace for use in that source file. It means that if you've got a class called `SoundTouchNet.Foo`, you can just write `Foo` elsewhere in the code.

Even though assemblies usually contain types within namespaces which match the assembly name (e.g. `Foo.Bar.dll` will usually contain types within the `Foo.Bar` namespace) this is *just* convention - the two kinds of names are entirely separate.

To make that type available in the first place, you need to add a *reference* to the assembly which contains it. Assuming you're using Visual Studio, go to Solution Explorer, right-click on the References folder-like icon, and select "Add reference". Personally I normally avoid the GAC, just adding references to either other projects in the same solution or specific files (which I usually put in a `lib` directory for sanity). You should also look at using [NuGet](http://nuget.org) for package management - many open source libraries are now made available as NuGet packages.

Comment: I can't remember how you tell the app to look in another directory for the assemblies, was something in the config right?

Comment: @TimothyP: Well typically you let Visual Studio copy the assembly to the output directory...

Comment: Yes but doesn't that just place the dll's in the same directory as the exe?, You mentioned a "lib" directory, so I thought <rootdir>/exe + <rootdir>/lib/dlls

Comment: Ah ok you're talking about the solution, I thought you meant the output... you know have a clean directory structure for the output instead of a dir with the exe and then lots of dlls, sorry

Comment: anyway just found it, it's the probing element in the config file, but I'm totally off topic here

Answer (score 0):

you need to register your external dll in the Global Assembly cache,

```
 gacutil.exe /i [Assembly]
```

the calls are pretty easy, here is the reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: it doesn't "need" to be in the GAC at all, and I would suggest it is very very rare to do this. The last time I used the GAC, it was purely for VB=>C# COM interop purposes. Other than that, I never touch it.

Comment: @MarcGravell, maybe I didn't understand the question, but I saw that the OP mentioning the GAC, so my intention was to mention the registration additional to the "physycal copy" of the file, but maybe you are right.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio:

Check the "How to: Add and Remove References in Visual Studio (C#)" in MSDN:

[MSDN - Adding / Removing references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)